# Removing Hash from URL in Ember & SP2013

Tags: iis, ember.js

Does anyone have any approaches for switching from Hashes to the HTML5 History API (which is done through Ember's API 1.0.0)? I have an SP site in which the default.aspx page loads Ember then routes currently are off of the root by using hashes ex: http://webserver/#/home.

[image]

I implemented a solution using App.Router's location and rootURL (shown above). In addition I used IIS Rewrite rules to perform redirects if a user navigates directly to /home (requesting http://webserver/home redirects the user to http://webserver/pages/default.aspx/home). Ultimately what I'm trying to do is remove "/pages/default.aspx" from being present in window.location.pathname. The problem is that Ember is loaded from default.aspx so none of the other routes work unless the rootURL is in place.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the answer, but this is entirely an IIS question not the things that it's tagged. You need to serve the ember .html on any route that is requested, and the way to achieve that is to configure your webserver to do that however it needs to be configured (haven't used IIS for a very long time and no idea how that config would look)

Comment: I thought about it more and the best solution might be to use an HTTP module.